# When webpage accessed by admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-views

I'd like the rendered webpage requested by admin to differ from the one requested by a user. Can that be achieved? Can I check whether the request has been sent from admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Check you `request` object

```
request.user.is_superuser
```

This will return `True` if user is Admin and `False` for regular User.